# How to do non-GET requests on your own API

Tags: java, rest, crud

I followed [this](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/12/spring-boot-mongodb-crud-example-tutorial.html) guide to create my own REST API. I am trying to consume my API that I built from the guide but I ran into some trouble when it came to using any request that wasn't a `GET` request. When I tried doing a delete request. (`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees/3`)

I would get a `405 error` and I'm not sure why (I do not have any password protection in my local host). I want to understand how I can create requests other than `GET`. I tried using query parameters for my `POST` request, but it was unsuccessful.

I looked at all the other StackOverFlow Similar Questions and I couldn't find anything.

**EDIT1: I am using a simple Java Application to do this.**

This was the code I used in order to do my `GET` requests

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees";
try {
  String result = "";
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String line;
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
  }
  rd.close();
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: while it is good to know how the api called using raw code, i recommend you to take a look at https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html or https://square.github.io/okhttp/ if at all you are planning to write production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace this `URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();`

to this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: This helped me to do the DELETE requests. I tried using this for the POST request and I received a 400 error code. I tried also copy pasting my link into web browser and it wouldn't work at all. I am not sure it is when I use query parameters that my link isn't working.

Comment: take a look at this for when what to use https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate (rest-template) to consume rest api.

for delete, you can do something like

```
private void deleteEmployee() {
        Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < String, String > ();
        params.put("id", "1");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.delete(DELETE_EMPLOYEE_ENDPOINT_URL, params);
    }
```

please check   https://www.javaguides.net/2019/06/spring-resttemplate-get-post-put-and-delete-example.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html and https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

hope these provide enough info

Comment: for simple url connection why need resttemplate, question is simple java application and not any framework involved!

Comment: @silentsudo said what I wanted to say. I am not using springframework for this, I want to do this on a simple java application.

Comment: the tutorial he posted in the question has a spring boot framework so I suggested rest-template